# Destructor called when I return new instance of object in if-statement

Tags: c++, destructor

```
class Vec
{
public:
    unsigned int dim;
    float* elements;

    // Constructors
    Vec() : dim(0), elements(nullptr) {}

    Vec(unsigned int dim, ...) : dim(dim), elements(new float[dim])
    {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, dim);

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
        {
            // C/C++ promotes floats passed as variable arguments to double,
            // so you need to use va_arg(args, double) and cast it to float
            elements[i] = static_cast<float>(va_arg(args, double));
        }

        va_end(args);
    }

    Vec(unsigned int dim, float value) : dim(dim), elements(new float[dim])
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
        {
            elements[i] = value;
        }
    }

    // Destructor
    ~Vec()
    {
        delete[] elements;
    }
};


Vec vecAdd(Vec* v1, Vec* v2)
{
    if (v1->dim != v2->dim)
    {
        //Vec VEC_UNDEFINED;
        //return VEC_UNDEFINED;
        return Vec;
    }

    Vec ret(v1->dim);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ret.dim; i++)
    {
        ret.elements[i] = v1->elements[i] + v2->elements[i];
    }

    return ret;
}
```

If I call the class and add to vectors together and return the ret object the destructor is called and all ret.elements get deleted which I don't want.

If I would commant out the "return Vec;" in my boundary check and uncommant the "//Vec VEC_UNDEFINED; //return VEC_UNDEFINED;" the destructor would not be called and the code works as expected. Why does C++ behave like this?

Comment: `Vec(unsigned int dim, ...)` is not recommended. If you need, you can use variadic templates in C++.

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: @user12002570 How can I improve my code?

Comment: @LucasMenke If you want a review of your code, it might be more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: post minimal example, add some prints in the constructor/desctructor, and maybe check move assignment feature.

Comment: `Vec vecAdd(Vec* v1, Vec* v2)` -- This is a bug.  Your `Vec` object is being returned by value, meaning that a copy will be made.  Your `Vec` class failed to implement the [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: you should use `std::initializer_list` instead `va_list`!

Comment: Did you mean this https://godbolt.org/z/zhEzYrE7P ?

Comment: @lucas *Why does C++ behave like this?* -- Go to the **Managing resources** section of [the rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).  The example shown there is almost exactly what you are doing, and it shows the failure of doing things this way.  Also, this: `int main() { Vec v1(1,1); Vec v2 = v1; }` duplicates the issue you are probably seeing, and you don't need that variadic constructor to see this, or even the call to `vecAdd`.

Comment: For me it looks like you are trying jump over one skill level. You have problem understanding how to pass arguments properly.

Comment: @user12002570 "Why does C++ behave like this?" Rings far to close to violating Code Review's "We expect you, as the author, to understand why the code is written the way that it is." rule for my liking.

Comment: @lucas What's meant with "a minimal verifiable example" is a self-contained code including the caller side, which demonstrate the problem you are having. Could you please edit the question with an example of what the caller code looks like?

Comment: @user12002570 Ah I see :) "Promotion" is actually a formal technical term in the language. In this case an oddball rule known as "the default argument promotions" which exists in both languages. I'll delete comments as well. As a side note, using variadic argument lists is considered very bad practice in both languages as well.

Comment: @MarekR I am not really sure if the website (godbolt ) reproduces my error. You are absoultly right, I should focus on the basic skills first. Thank you for your time & effort.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie "the rule of 3" is a great ressource. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improve your code using templates (assuming your vector dimension is fixed which seems to make sense based on your code) it would look something like this (otherwise just use std::vector or wrap that)

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t dim_v>
class Vec final
{
public:
    explicit Vec(const float(&values)[dim_v]) 
    {
        std::copy(std::begin(values),std::end(values),m_values.begin());
    }

    explicit Vec(float value)
    {
        std::fill(m_values.begin(), m_values.end(), value);
    }

    // Destructor
    ~Vec() = default;

    const auto& values() const noexcept
    {
        return m_values;
    }

    constexpr auto& dims() const noexcept
    {
        return dim_v;
    }

private:
    std::array<float, dim_v> m_values;
};

int main()
{
    Vec v{ {0.f,1.f,2.f} };

    for (const auto& value : v.values())
    {
        std::cout << value << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new to C++ & I first need to learn the basics. I never saw templates before, but they look very interesting.

Comment: They are more than interesting, they are one of C++ most powerful tools ;)
But yes most of the time they are not considered "beginners" material. Though I think new and delete are more dangerous. (Memory leaks, nullptr dereferences etc). And in a lot of cases they can avoid type unsafe code like using `va_args` or replace macros